# Material UI TextField element not focused after clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a TextField inside a pop-up dialog however even after being clicked the TextField element still does not focus and I can't enter in any text. I saw on various posts that adding in id and name will fix the problem but in my case, nothing changed. How can I resolve this issue?

```
return (
        <Dialog onClose = { () => setPopupOpen(false) } open = { open } fullWidth = { true } maxWidth = "md"> 

            <DialogTitle> { popupTitle } </DialogTitle>

            <DialogContent> <FormControl> 
                
                <TextField
                    name = "popup-title"
                    id = "popup-title"
                    variant = "outlined" 
                    margin = "dense"
                    label = "Title"
                    type = "text"
                    text = { true }
                    placeholder = "Specify reasons"
                    value = { reason }
                    onChange = { (e) => setReason(e.target.value) }
                    required
                    sx = { { width: "750px" } }
                />`

            </FormControl> </DialogContent>

        </Dialog>
    )
```

Comment: I had a focus issue similar to this (a text field on a dialog form) and I had to do: ```onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} ```

In my case the grid from which the dialog was opened was getting the focus when I clicked into the text field. 

Probably not the best solution, and potentially problematic, but it at least stopped the issue for me.

Comment: do you get any erros in the console log like maximum call stack size exceeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using a useRef hook which set focus to the TextField onClick.

```
const popUp = () => { 

    const inpRef = useRef(null);
    ...
    
    return ( 

        <TextField 
            inputRef = { inpRef } 
            onClick = { () => inpRef.current.focus() }
            ...
        /> 
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

set position as relative to your input and also set z-index as a number and try. it should be work

for example:

```
.inputClassName {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I gave that a shot by adding those properties in the sx but it didn't work